# Issue with unlinking AWS linked logins (ex. Facebook)

Tags: ios, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Referring : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=178597&tstart=0#618613

When trying to unlink facebook login from AWS by,

```
  //aws logout
  let unlinkParams = AWSCognitoIdentityUnlinkIdentityInput()
  unlinkParams.identityId = "COGNITO_ID"
  unlinkParams.logins = ["graph.facebook.com" : "TOKEN"]
  unlinkParams.loginsToRemove = ["graph.facebook.com"]
  let cognitoIdentity : AWSCognitoIdentity = AWSCognitoIdentity.defaultCognitoIdentity()
  cognitoIdentity.unlinkIdentity(unlinkParams).continueWithBlock({ task -> AnyObject! in
                return nil
            })
```

Linked logins becomes "DISABLED" from "graph.facebook.com". Is this expected behaviour or something going wrong in logout process?

Answer (score 2):

The previously linked login becoming DISABLED is expected behavior. I would double check with Bob's reply after that forum post, he suggests not using defaultCognitoIdentity().

Comment: I had also tried to replace defaultCognitoIdentity with anonymous identity which did not work for me. As per doc unlink() makes last linked identity inaccessible.